# Nonresponsive UI starting a few days ago; no obvious resource shortage

Tags: gnome

The mouse stops and moves jerkily, and sometimes won't register clicks. Gnome stopped responding a few hours ago--everything looks fine, but no clicks on menu items do anything.

I've been running Ubuntu 10.10 since it was released; 8GB RAM and a 60GB SSD. I haven't added any hardware or software recently except the Ubuntu recommended updates; the last thing was the bitcoin client a week ago.

The mouse works on other computers, rebooting does nothing, top shows 3 CPU cores free and over a gig of ram left. I don't know what else to look at.

Comment: So in otherwords, you've got a frozen GNOME. I get that all the time. Were you doing anything important that wasn't saved? If not, then pull the plug and reboot. Happens to me about once or twice a week. (And yes, I know I'm answering in a comment)

Comment: Unfortunately, rebooting isn't fixing it. Feels a bit different from frozen gnome, as well, with the pauses in mouse movement; and before the GUI stopped working altogether it would also stop accepting keyboard input for seconds at a time. Wouldn't even buffer the keystrokes.

Comment: It might be related to the issue described by jrgifford, which I am also experience at random boots (about 1/10 boots). Whatever is causing the bug on us randomly might be happening on your persistently.

Answer (score 1):

If you recently upgraded to the 2.6.35-25 kernel this past week, it's causing some folks including myself a lot of problems, but not exactly what you are describing (CPU overloading):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/703553

In case that could have anything to do with your problems, try booting to the previous version of the kernel in grub, 2.6.35-24

Comment: Sadly, I have not upgraded kernels since 2.6.32-27. Perhaps I'll try.